# Is it possible to fix len(df) when this is being executed in a while loop?

Tags: python

I'm writing a while loop to analyze a `dataset` and I'd like to iterate over the last 50 columns or so of the `dataframe`. In the iterations the code takes a column, performs a calculation and generates a new column for each column it looped over at the end of the existing `dataframe`. I've written a `while loop` to do this and the general idea of this while loops works fine.

However, in the while loop I've currently written the code below. The problem is that the while loops keeps running while `x < len(df.columns)` but the code also adds columns to the existing `dataframe`. As a result the while loop will go on forever as x will always be smaller than `len(df.columns)`.

```
x=48 ###start at column 49
while x < len(df.columns):
    x=x+1
    df.loc[df.iloc[:,x] >0,str(df.columns[x])+"_y/n"] = 1
    df[str(df.columns[x])+"_y/n"].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

I want to load a `dataframe` and use the initial length of this `dataframe` to set the threshold for my while loop.

My question: Is it possible to fix the length of the initial `dataframe`? So that this while loop stops when x reaches the initial length of `df`.

Thank you!

Note: I'm a beginner at Python, so I appreciate any other suggestions to write my code more efficient/less messy but then I would highly appreciate a detailed explanation why/how to.

Comment: The simplest way I can think of is assign it to a variable and use that in the condition. That way it won't keep reevaluating `len(df.columns)`.

Comment: Just call `len(df.columns)` once before the loop and store the result in a variable. Then use that variable in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=48
initial_length = len(df.columns)
while x < initial_length:
    x += 1
    ...
```